# Examples of exceptional C# source code documentation

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm wondering, what are some examples of C# projects which have exceptional source-level documentation?

Thank you.

Comment: **[This BitStream class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/bitstream.aspx)** contains sufficient XML comments such that the entire documentation help file can be generated directly from the source. It also contains a sample application that makes it clearly obvious how the class works, and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptional documentation is a subjective thing.

I think it is much better to focus on writing clear, concise, readable code, and only document the business purpose for code (where the purpose is not clear) than to worry about good documentation.

The documentation, in practice, rarely ever keeps up with the code changes. (At least in my experience)

Comment: Self-documenting code is a bit of a myth. It is true that classes can be self-describing, but relationships between classes (and the appropriate usage scenarios for those classes) are not always so clearly apparent. This is where documentation becomes worth its weight in gold. Were this not true, Microsoft would simply release its .NET framework, and not bother to write any documentation or code samples for it.

Comment: I would hope that code changes don't get made unless the documentation reflects those changes.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I guess I have to agree.  I was thinking mainly of internal code comments as the question described.  I had forgotten that companies that write APIs tend to use the XML Comment feature (technically code comments) in C# and VB.NET to create external documentation.  Most of our external documentation comes from sources other than code comments, so to me they are different entities, and we do keep our external documentation up-to-date.  Our development process includes documentation reviews as well as code reviews to ensure this.

Comment: We do use the XML Comments feature, but mostly to provide info in the intellisense balloons.

Comment: @David Stratton - I have roughly 9 months experience working with C#. I come from a C99 and Python background. I know cultures vary from language to language, and platform to platform. I asked this question to get a better sense of what the C# community views as exemplary source-level  comments and documentation. I understand that opinions may vary.

Comment: With that comment, I am voting to re-open even though I was one of the people that originally voted to close this as subjective.

Comment: @Ncarlson - have you seen this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Comment: @David Stratton - Yeah. I was originally using javadoc style comments, but I've since switched over to the XML tags since that's what most of the C# specific tools read. That said, my comments are rather basic: summary, params and return. I just want to make sure that I'm writing the best documentation I can. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik usually documents their code exceptionally well. Check out their [MVC extensions project on Codeplex](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/) to see for yourself.

Comment: A large portion of the source files in that project are completely undocumented.